# How do I use read.csv file in R?

Tags: r, read.csv

I am trying to read a csv file in R to start cleaning data. Currently working on my Google Data Analytics Capstone Project. Any guidance would be helpful

I have included the code I input and the error I get from the system

> daily_activity <- read.csv('dailyActivity_merged.csv')

Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
cannot open file 'dailyActivity_merged.csv': No such file or directory

Comment: R has a concept of "current working directory" where it will look for files when you give it a file name. Chances are this csv file isn't in your current working directory. You can run `getwd()` to see the current working directory or run `list.files()` to view the files in the current working directory. Make sure that's where the file you are trying to load is.